# Need to place Figcaption below responsive Image

Tags: html

I have used some code from stackoverflow oct 13 by Mark e Haas. The aim is to have two images side by side with a fig caption below them and for the images to respond to the screen size.
The image sizing is working inthe sense that te images stay on the screen as the size shrinks. The issue is with the  I have tried amending various parameters but the caption always appears on the left of the image not below it. Before i start invetigating using a grid to place the image in is it possible to have the  place itself below the Image preferably in the middle.
Code is below.

```
<style type="text/css">
<!-- css  -->
#content {    /* main display pane for all content  */

  float: left;

  /* width: 595px; */

  width: 75%;

  min-height: 600px;

  /* border: 1px solid #ccc; */

  margin-left: 1px;

  padding: 5px;

  padding-bottom: 8px ;
 background: #white;
}
div.fill-screen {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 10;
  text-align: bottom; 
}
img.make-it-fit {
    max-width: 99%;
    max-height: 10%;
    float: left;
    margin: auto;



}
img.make-right {
    max-width: 99%;
    max-height: 10%;
    float: right;
    margin: auto;

}
figure {
 
  padding: 4px;
  margin: auto;
}

figcaption {
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: bottom;
}
/Style
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/trsppic.css" />
</head>
<div id=content>
<!-- <div class='fill-screen'> -->
<figure>
<img class='make-it-fit' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Leaning_Tower_of_Pisa.jpg' width=30%>
<figcaption>test</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
<img class='make-right' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Leaning_Tower_of_Pisa.jpg' width=30%>
</figure> 

</div</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, i had modified a little bit the HTML but works fine.

```css
 .fig_box {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            height: fit-content;
            position: relative;
        }

        .make-it-fit {
            width: 50%;
        }

        span.caption {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            width: 50%;
            left: 0;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/trsppic.css" />
</head>
<div id=content>
    <!-- <div class='fill-screen'> -->
    <div class="figure_content">
        <div class="fig_box">
            <img class='make-it-fit'
                src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Leaning_Tower_of_Pisa.jpg' />
            <span class="caption">test1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="fig_box">
            <img class='make-it-fit'
                src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Leaning_Tower_of_Pisa.jpg' />
            <span class="caption">test2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: This code is perfect RootatKali and does what is required have tested on several devices and the images respond and keep there position.

Comment: good! please, if this solution work and you want to do it, check my answer pls.

Comment: Sorry just completed testing the solution on various devices.  It seems the picture element always stays on the top of the drop down menu for small screens. Any idea

Comment: Fixed it was missing a Z-index on mobile dropdown.